# Quantum mechanics: How do the atoms in an electronic circuit enter a smaller orbit on the filament of an incandescent light bulb?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, thermal-radiation

Bear in mind that this is not a homework question, and I have put together some stuff to work on from below:

http://www.doublexscience.org/how-fluorescent-lights-work-quantum-mechanics-in-the-home/

I am quoting from that source, and placing my question in boldface right below.

> They light up when an electric current runs through a thin wire made of tungsten, which heats up.

**I thought it was a filament in which the atoms moved through, entered a smaller orbit, and produced black body radiation?**

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation

> Light is a form of energy that can be released by an atom. It is made up of many small particle-like packets that have energy and momentum but no mass. These particles, called light photons, are the most basic units of light. (For more information, see How Light Works.)

**So light is now "energy"? I thought light was electromagnetic radiation. How can energy of the light have no mass when atoms running through tungsten/filament entered another orbit?**

Comment: Your first link discusses fluorescent lights but your question is talking about the filaments of incandescent lights.

Answer (score 3):

The black-body radiation from a heated filament is nothing to do with electrons entering smaller orbits. In a solid the lattice vibrations cause fluctuations in electron density and in particular oscillating dipoles. These oscillating dipoles are the main source of the EM radiation that we see as black body radiation.

I suspect you're getting mixed up with fluorescent lights. In these free electrons excite the electrons in gas atoms to a higher energy state, and when the atoms relax back to the ground state photons are emitted. This is an entirely different mechanism from black body radiation.

Comment: … as the article goes on to say, "Of course even incandescent bulbs are quantum-mechanical underneath: after all, everything is quantum if you examine it closely enough."

Answer (score 1):

> So light is now "energy"? I thought light was electromagnetic radiation.

Photons (what light/EMR is made of) *have* energy: $E=h\nu$ ($h$ is Planck's Constant, and $\nu$ is the frequency).

As John Rennie explained, it has nothing to do with "atoms [electrons] running through...another orbit". Please read up on **black body radiation**.

Answer (score 0):

Just to express doubt about the mechanism as described by John Rennie: I think he correctly describes black-body radiation from a filament as being the result of what are essentially classically oscillating charge densities driven by lattice vibration. I think he may be wrong in suggesting that the radiation is mainly from fluctuating electron cloud density as driven by the lattice vibrations. I would expect the conduction electrons form pretty much a stationary background cloud surrounding the metal ions, and it is the oscillations of those positive metal ions themselves which is the main source of thermal radiation.

After all, the conduction electrons do not make a big contribution to the specific heat of a metal, so I'm not sure how much they are taking part in the thermal vibrations.